# How to hide shape when scrolling up in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I scroll up, the text disappears but the shape doesn't disappear, it's like the image below, it will display over other widgets. How to hide it like text ?

[image]

[Here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=03a68ec080f878912ba693dd33891446) is the source code, I uploaded to dartpad

Comment: As per the [help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it's best if you include the relevant code inside your question, so in the case that any external websites shut down the code will still be present in the question :) (That being said uploading to dartpad is still useful! You can do both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68888017/9063935) answer, it looks to me like a potential bug with `ListTile`. If you draw the blue rounded border using a `DecoratedBox` widget to wrap your `ListTile` instead of directly inside of the `ListTile`, the issue will go away :)

```dart
DecoratedBox(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
  child: ListTile(
//  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
//    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1),
//    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
//  ),
//  .. rest of arguments
  ),
),
```

I'm not sure if this bug has been reported, but if not feel free to report it on the Flutter github repo to have it fixed :) Or perhaps fix it yourself and submit a pull request!

Comment: oh, it works as I expected. Thanks friend

Comment: yes, multiple issues with ListTile currently.